# How to know if the 3d-view is in camera mode or not?

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view

I'd like to know if the context 3d-view is in camera mode or not using python?
What is the code for that, I can't find it in the API.

Answer (score 3):

See context.space_data.region_3d.view_perspective which returns a string from an emum of PERSP, ORTHO and CAMERA.

thanks to kaio !